# Variables in Laravel Validation

Tags: php, variables, laravel, rules

I was wondering if it's possible if you can add variables to validation rules in the laravel framework.

For example:

```
$size= 2000;
public static $rules = array(
        'filename'=>'required', 
        'file' => 'max:' . $this->size
    );
```

but this works:

```
public static $rules = array(
        'filename'=>'required', 
        'file' => 'max:2000'
    );
```

But this doesn't seem to do it.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: What doesn't work ? What `Auth::user()->role->filesize` returns and what do you get now ?

Comment: edited my post to a more clearer example

Comment: Does that work with `'file' => 'max:2000'` ?

Comment: What errors you get ?

Comment: Is `file` your `file` input's name ?

Comment: Yes, it's my input's name. Without this rule it works perfectly

Comment: 'file' => 'max:2000' is working, still not with a variable

Comment: You should tell about the `error` you are getting.

Comment: I don't think Laravel itself read the `$rules` property. Does `Validator::make(Input::all(), Model::$rules)` _work_ for you?

Comment: That's what I'm using to validate. The" model::$rules" are these rules

Answer (score 2):

Based off of your snippet, you are trying to set the rules when you declare the rules property.  If you are setting rules as an object property, you should do it in the `__construct()` as you can't do it when you are declaring variables

```
<?php
class foo{
    public static $var=[
        'asdf'=>1234,
        'qwerty'=>bar::returnVar()
    ];
}
class bar{
    public static function returnVar(){
        return 5678;
    }

}
print_r(foo::$var);
```

The above snippet throws an error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ']' in C:\scripts\test.php on line 5`

So your best bet is to set it in your `__construct()` or just before you validate.

Comment: I know, the answer is still applicable.  Follow the advice I gave to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem.
I'm a novice when it comes to laravel, but what I did was to add a hidden field on the form with the value I wanted to use. Then I just had to add such field in the validator.

```
{{ Form::hidden('max', 2000 }}

...

public static $rules = array(
    'filename'=>'required', 
    'file' => 'max:max'
);
```